# Store and Encrypt Contact Form 7 Submissions in Database?

Tags: database, forms, plugin-contact-form-7, encryption

I have an additional security requirement (in addition to SSL) and I'm looking for a method (either a plugin or custom solution) of how to encrypt and store submissions from [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) in the database.
For example there are plugins such as [Flamingo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/) that allow the submissions to to be stored in the DB, there are fore other form platforms such as [Gravitate Encryption](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravitate-encryption/) that encrypt the submissions in the DB.
Is there an option or method to encrypt CF7 submission data within the SQL database?

Comment: I don't know of an existing plugin, but you can hook into `wpcf7_mail_sent` (see code [here](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/contact-form-7/trunk/includes/submission.php#L164)), [encrypt the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969740/encrypt-files-using-pgp-in-php) and save it in the database

Comment: Keep in mind if the data is sensitive enough to encrypt, sending it via email at all is insecure.

Comment: @WebElaine It won't be sent via email just needs to be stored in DB

Comment: Probably best to contact the plugin author directly.

Answer (score 3):

As @kero said, use a CF7 hook. I'd use the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook. Grab data from the CF7 form object's fields, and use those values to store data.

I wrote a post to myself on how to get data from the CF7 form object here: http://securitydawg.com/changing-contact-form-7-with-the-wpcf7_before_send_mail-hook/ . You could use that to get started, just insert your code/function that reads the fields from the CF7 object and then store that data.

Good luck!